# Should this be moved to a background task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a recruitment system with Users and Jobs.

Between them there exists a has_many relationship :through Potentials.

This will essentially allow admin to see how likely a user is to be a good fit for a job

To do this, I have an after_create and an after_save event like so --

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :create_potentials
  after_save :set_potentials

  private
    def create_potentials
      Job.all.each do | job | 
        potential = Potential.new
        potential.job_id = job.id
        potential.user_id = self.id
        potential.save!
      end
    end

    def set_potentials
      self.potentials.each do |potential|
        potential.level = potential.find_potential
        potential.save!
      end
    end
```

This worries me quite a bit though. The first is that it seems a bit wacky that I'm using an entire model just for one attribute, "potential".

The second is that after a user is created, I am creating Potentials for the total amount of jobs.

For now, the jobs are going to be relatively few ( i.e under 30 ), but that's a lot of potential computational tasks.

Can the after_create and after_save events run asynchronously?

Comment: +1 because your question is a useful one to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering how simple the insert/update logic is and how potentially underperforming any ruby approach will be you might want to consider doing this explicitly through the database.

For example, your `create_potentials` would be something like:

```
insert into potentials select :user_id, id from jobs
```

where `:user_id` is being passed as a query parameter, and handle `set_potential` in a similar way (nested query probably in update statement).

At some point you might want to move this logic into one of these https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs or even fall back into implementing those 2 simple methods in ruby if logic gets complicated,

but for now simplest and least overkill approach seems to be to just use SQL, skip background queues and let the database handle this.

---

Also, whichever way you go, that potential table looks like something that will want to explode in size if your project kicks off, so consider how well your jobs schema fits into a rich document model (see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIWVFUtBV1Q and http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid?view=asciicast)

Depending on rest of your setup, you might find it suits your needs better then a traditional database

Comment: Hey bbozo, I love this solution, but am a bit new sql and am having trouble getting the insert to work. Do you mind going in a bit further on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Gem like Delayed Job to run methods asynchronously.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

The answer to your optimisation question probably depends on, as you say, how many jobs, users, and therefore 'potentials' are likely to exist. The right approach would also depend on whether you need to query them using SQL, or whether you can calculate them on the fly.

Your current association code can be abbreviated somewhat by creating the potential through the association. And if you decide to create a `Potential` for every `User` for every `Job`, you'll want to use [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each) to avoid loading every job into memory at once.

```
  Job.find_each { |job| job.potentials.create!(user_id: self.id) }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your Qsn, `for every new user created. Entries are made into potential table for each job id along with the user_id.` and

For update of user entry, `potential level is being updated for all the potential table entries for that user which equals total no of jobs present.`

In case you are looking for real time updates for the user, then you need to skip the cron part and implement the logic to reduce the no of queries.  If this is not a restriction then 
would suggest to use cron jobs to process this, Using redis/resque to process after_create and after_save tasks. When any user is created or updated, enqueqe the task, these jobs will be processed by the running redis server.

As suggested in the answer by doctororange, delayed job can also be looked upon if you want to process tasks on regular intervals irrespective of any changes for user table.